# Не работает цикл Pascal (repeat until)

Tags: pascal

Должна выводится таблица значений функций в виде x=  y=
Почему-то выводится только первое значение x,y.

```
   var a, b, x0, x1, dx, y, n : real;
begin
 ...
  write('Enter a, b, x0, x1, dx: ');
  readln(a, b, x0, x1, dx); //3.1 1.5 0.5 1.5 0.25
  n:= x0;
  repeat
     y:= ((sqrt(a*x0))+b)/(sqr(sin(x0)/cos(x0)));
     writeln('x=', x0:5:2, ' y=', y:5:2);
     x0:= x0 + dx;
  until (x0>=n) and (x0<=x1);
  x0:= n;
```

Comment: a=3.1 b=1.5 x0=0.5 x1=1.5 dx=0.25
0.25 шаг функции от x=0.5 до x=1.5
должно получится так:
    x=0.5   y=...
    x=0.75 y=...
    x=1      y=...
    x=1.25 y=...
    x=1.5   y=...

Comment: Здесь достаточно простого цикла for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`until` означет "пока не":

```
repeat
  ...
until (x0 > x1);
```

то есть: повторять пока `x0` не станет больше `x1`.